# How to make text style look etched

Tags: android, text, styles

Is there a way to make text look etched?  I want the text in my textview to look etched.  I tried using negative values in the shadow, but 0 appears to be the lowest value.

Comment: No, you can use negatives as well, BTW. :)

Comment: You are correct.  The colors I was using resulted in the effect that it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use text shadow to do this.  First, make sure the shadow color is lighter than the text color and use something like this:

```
.etched {
    color: #222;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, it looks only like the aspect has changed - it still looks raised.

Comment: Don't forget, the text-shadow values will depend on the size of the text.  Test different values (and yes, try negatives) and you will find what you need.

Comment: Check out this article I just found for you:  http://css-snippets.com/engraved-text/